# Access a database (out of multiple) in Rails on runtime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Suppose if I have multiple databases with same tables but different values in them. So is that possible to select a database for querying for a particular session based on button click or a dropdown.
I want to make a generalized app which works the same for all, online Databse changes as per the session or current instance data.

Eg: Consider a student app for school. Assuming basic operation on all students will remain same even if the belong to different schools.

- School 1(DB 1)
- - Student -table 1
- - Books -table 2
- School 2(DB 2)
- - Student -table 1
- - Books -table 2
- School 3(DB 3)
- - Student -table 1
- - Books -table 2

.....so on

Now how to switch between different DB, based on menu where we ask then school name.
i.e

- school 1 --(connect to)-- school 1(DB 1)
- school 2 --(connect to)-- school 2(DB 2)
- school 3 --(connect to)-- school 3(DB 3)

So how to set DB connection before querying or before starting accessing records that is at runtime.
Thanks in advance.

I got how to connect to db on model level that is with **establish_connection** but DB is fixed here, but I want to connect to DB on real time depending on User Input and use the connection throughout same session. So is there any way?

Comment: Read [the manual](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html). And what you are describing is basically [multitenancy](https://www.gartner.com/en/information-technology/glossary/multitenancy).

Comment: @max thanks for answering.

Comment: @max can u help me with how can we implement multitenancy in best way in RoR

Comment: no do your own homework

Comment: This was solved using multitenancy

Comment: I used apartment gem https://github.com/influitive/apartment